# Webpack exclude spec files

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia

I am using Webpack combined with Aurelia and Typescript. For my project setup I used the Aurelia skeleton: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack
I did not like the spec files to live under a separate directory from the app files. So I moved all the spec files to the same folder. This led to having all the spec files being bundled together with my app files into the app bundle which is undesirable of course.

I was under the impression that Webpack only loads the entry file (in the Skeleton project this is the ./src/main file) which on his turn loads in all other necessary files. This would mean that my spec files should not get included, but they do...

Am I wrong or am I missing something here?

**EDIT**: Made a dependency graph of my app and found out that this file is loading all my spec files:
`./~/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader-webpack.js`

This file is running this RegEx which matches all files: `./src ^\.\/.*$`

Comment: They shouldn't. This is why in `test/spec.bundle.js` all spec files are imported: `var testContext = require.context('./unit', true, /\.spec\.(ts|js)$/);`. Can you break things down and give more information about your file structure and main imports? The skeleton that you provided should not be affected from weird imports IMHO.

Comment: @dotcs made an edit to my question. Does this mean the issue is in `aurelia-loader-webpack`? I guess not right? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

No longer the case with webpack-plugin moved forward unless you specify includeAll option for it.
When you specify your entry point webpack will trace only referenced modules so spec files won't get into any bundles. unless you specifically import them.